# Data becomes modified during printf

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

After I read in some data from a file, an assign it to a struct type record within a node the data matches that of the file. After I leave the read function and go back in to main the data still remains the same. But when I attempt to print it, it becomes a jumbled mess.

**Load Function**

```
void load(FILE *file, Node *head)
{
    char tempArtist[30]={'\0'}, tempAlbum[30]={'\0'}, tempTitle[30]={'\0'}, tempGenre[30]={'\0'},tempSpace='\0';
    SongLength *tempLength=NULL;
    int tempPlay=0, tempRating=0, tempMins=0, tempSecs=0;

    tempLength = (SongLength*)malloc(sizeof(SongLength));

    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempArtist);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempAlbum);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempTitle);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempGenre);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempMins);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempSecs);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempPlay);
    fscanf(file,"%s",&tempRating);
    fscanf(file,"%c",&tempSpace);

    tempLength->mins=&tempMins;
    tempLength->secs=&tempSecs;

    head->data->album=tempAlbum;
    head->data->artist=tempArtist;
    head->data->genre=tempGenre;
    head->data->song=tempTitle;
    head->data->length=tempLength;
    head->data->played=tempPlay;
    head->data->rating=tempRating;
}
```

**Print Test Function**

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *loadFile = NULL;
    Node *head=NULL;

    head=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    head->data=(Record*)malloc(sizeof(Record));
    head->data->length=(SongLength*)malloc(sizeof(SongLength));

    loadFile=fopen("records.txt","r");

    load(loadFile,head);
    head->data->artist; // artist matches the name in load file (aka snoop)
    printf("%s", head->data->artist); // When trying to print here it prints a smiley face
}
```

**Extra info for easy replication**

```
typedef struct songlength
{
    int *mins;
    int *secs;
}SongLength;


typedef struct record
{
    char *artist;
    char *album;
    char *song;
    char *genre;
    struct songlength *length;
    int played;
    int rating;

}Record;

typedef struct node
{
    struct node *pPrev;
    struct record *data;
    struct node *pNext;

}Node;
```

**File Data Format**

```
snoop
heartbeat
swiggity
rap
03
10
25
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you assign pointers to local arrays to the `head` structure.

For example, the array `tempArtist` will *go out of scope* once the function `load` returns, so any pointers pointing to that array (like `head->artist`) will be stray pointers, and derefeencing those pointer will lead to said undefined behavior.

Comment: So, what would be the best way to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: @user3482104 Two solutions really: Either you dynamically allocate the pointers in the structure and copy the strings, or you make the strings in the structure arrays and copy the strings.